# Not specifying an actual name for positional argument in function definition

Tags: python, python-3.x

A single-parameter function can be written out like this:

```py
import datetime

def func1(mydate):
    frmt = '%d-%m-%Y'
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(mydate, frmt)
```

The Python 3.5 interpreter also accepts this form of the same function:

```py
def func2(str):
    frmt = '%d-%m-%Y'
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(str, frmt)
```

I am having trouble learning/researching why the latter single-parameter function works correctly.

Researching the web using phrases like "defining function with argument that is an actual type keyword", "type function as argument", etc., yields no information.  If anybody is familiar with this behavior, or can direct me to a resource, I would be very grateful.  Here is a verifiable example that can be pasted into the interpreter:

```py
import datetime

def func1(mydate):
    frmt = '%d-%m-%Y'
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(mydate, frmt)

def func2(str):
    frmt = '%d-%m-%Y'
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(str, frmt)


# test

todaysdate = "28-10-2019"
print(func1(todaysdate) == func2(todaysdate))
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: `def func2(str):` this is valid but not recommended. You are not passing a `type`. You are saying the variable you are passing in has the name `str` thus you are overwriting the reserved `str` object. Try doing `str(2)` in `func2` and you will see this.

Answer (score 3):

Python doesn't stop you from "shadowing" built-in object types for variable names. It's not recommended of course. However, you're simply creating a variable with the name `str`.

Answer (score 0):

I'll put this in an answer instead of leaving my comment but just to add upon the other answer. You aren't passing a type to your function, you are overwriting a built in type. Though python allows this, you shouldn't do it. It will lead to confusion and errors down the road.

```
def func(str):
    print(str)
    print(str(2))

func('test')
```

Output:

```
test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    func('test')
  File "main.py", line 3, in func
    print(str(2))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Versus:

```
def func(my_str):
    print(my_str) # prints test
    print(str(2)) # prints 2

func('test')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime

def func1(mydate):
    frmt = '%d-%m-%Y'
    return str(datetime.datetime.strptime(mydate, frmt))

def func2(str):
    frmt = '%d-%m-%Y'
    return str(datetime.datetime.strptime(str, frmt))


# test

todaysdate = "28-10-2019"
print(func1(todaysdate) == func2(todaysdate))
```

this program gives you overview of the error by overriding str() function.

just see monkey patching concept in python.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/monkey-patching-in-python-dynamic-behavior/